# Dockerizing Scrapy - scrapy entrypoint not receiving command args

Tags: python, docker, scrapy

(I'm fairly new to Docker here.) I am trying to Dockerize a [Scrapy](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/intro/tutorial.html) application. As a first step, I'm trying to start a project in the container - which creates and populates a directory structure - and attach a volume to the project directory for editing purposes.

First I need to call `scrapy startproject myScraper`; then I'd like to be calling custom commands like `scrapy shell` or `scrapy crawl myCrawler` on the container to run webcrawls.

Since all Scrapy commands begin by calling `scrapy`, I wrote this Dockerfile:

```
    FROM python:3
    COPY requirements.txt .
    RUN pip install --no-cache-dir -r requirements.txt
    ENTRYPOINT scrapy      #or so I thought was right ...
```

where `requirements.txt` is just `Scrapy.`  Now I have a couple of problems. First is that the ENTRYPOINT does not seem to work - specifically, when I run

```
    docker build -t scraper .
    docker run -it -v $PWD:/scraper --name Scraper scraper [SOME-COMMAND]
```

I just get back the `scrapy` usage help menu. (For example, if `SOME-COMMAND` is `shell` or `startproject scraper`.) I've tried a few variations with no success. Second, if the container stops, I'm not sure how to start it again (e.g., I can't pass a command to `docker start -ai Scraper`).

Part of the reason I'm trying to do these commands here, rather than as RUN and VOLUME in the Dockerfile, is that if the volume is created during the build process, it obscures the project directory rather than copying its contents from container to host volume. (That is, I get a copy of my empty host directory in the container instead of the populated directory set up by `scrapy startproject volumeDirectory`.)

I've looked my issue up and know I may be off-track with proper Docker, but it really feels like what I'm asking should be possible here.

Answer (score 0):

My recommendation would be to delete the `ENTRYPOINT` line; you can make it the default `CMD` if you'd like.  Then you can run

```
docker run -it -v $PWD:/scraper --name Scraper scraper scrapy ...
```

Your actual problem here is that if you use `ENTRYPOINT` (or `CMD` or `RUN`) with a bare string like you show, it gets [automatically wrapped in `sh -c`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#shell-form-entrypoint-example).  Then the command you pass on the command line is [combined with the entrypoint](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#understand-how-cmd-and-entrypoint-interact) and what you ultimately get as the main container command is

```
/bin/sh -c 'scrapy' '[some-command]'
```

and so the shell runs `scrapy` with no arguments, but if that string happened to contain `$1` or similar positional parameters, they could get filled in from command parameters.

If you add [explicit JSON-array syntax](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#exec-form-entrypoint-example) then Docker won't add the `sh -c` wrapper and your proposed syntax will work

```
ENTRYPOINT ["scrapy"]
```

but a number of other common tasks won't work.  For example, you can't easily get a debugging shell

```
# Runs "scrapy /bin/bash"
docker run --rm -it scraper /bin/bash
```

and using `--entrypoint` to overwrite things results in awkward command lines

```
docker run --rm --entrypoint /bin/ls scraper -lrt /scraper
```